# How to unlock xcode file to make edits from different computers?

Tags: xcode

How to unlock xcode file to make edits from different computers?
(I would prefer not the old fashion copy and paste in a new one)

thx

Comment: How do you end up with locked files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this, Open terminal and enter the following commands (Changing files and directories for your app if needed) In some cases you may need to add '-R' after chmod and chown.

[image]